# headerRight is shown in a millisecond and it disappear. (react-navigation)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using Kitten UI for navigation(It's just wrapper). 
I could render `title` and `headerLeft` but `headerRight` doesn't show up. (Image was attached at the very bottom of this question)

This is navBar.js (ThemedNavigationBar)

```
_renderRight(headerRight) {
    let windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const width = this.state.width
      ? (windowWidth - this.state.width) / 2
      : undefined;
    return headerRight && (
        <View style={[{width}, styles.right]}>{headerRight}</View>
      );

  }

render() {
    let options = this.props.headerProps.getScreenDetails(this.props.headerProps.scene).options;
    return (
      <View style={styles.layout}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this._renderTitle(options.title, options.headerTitle)}
          {this._renderLeft(options.headerLeft)}
          {this._renderRight(options.headerRight)}
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

This is My ChangePassword's navigationOption

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `Change Password`,
    tabBarVisible: false,
    headerRight: ( <- RIGHT HERE
      <Button   
        title='SAVE'
      />
    ),
    header: (headerProps) => {
      return <ThemedNavigationBar navigation={navigation} headerProps={headerProps}/>
    }
});
```

`<Button title='SAVE' />` is not showing up!

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

I'm getting this weird looking navigation when I set `styles.right.right` from 0 to 30. What is going on here?

```
left: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  right: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 30, <- I set right from 30 to 0 and I could see the button (But it shows just the part of the botton. Can I do it better?
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the exact value of width `{width: 40}` solved my problem! Thank you guys